# Draw a line separating north and south quadrants passing through the centre point

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry-generator

I have a layer with irregular polygons. I use the expression `point_on_surface($geometry)` to calculate the centre of gravity:

[image]

I would like a Geometry Generator expression to draw a line separating the north and south quadrants passing through the centre point. And another expression to calculate the total area of each quadrant and the percentage of each quadrant:

[image]

Comment: I notice your project CRS is EPSG:4326. I assume that's what your layers are in too. Do you have to use that or can you use a projected CRS at some other point? From what I'm seeing I think the CRS you use will influence how "straight" the line is (and how that's even defined).

Comment: does the solution have to be in a geometry generator? would be hard to achieve this way. adding a few processing tools together this should be doable, however.

Comment: I usually work with CRS EPSG:4326, EPSG:3857, EPSG:3035. I would like the solution to be compatible with all three. If possible, I would like it to be a complete solution for Geometry Generator

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with a geometry generator alone, using `split with lines` is crucial here and it modifies the actual data, this is beyond the geometry generator's ability...

Comment: You said "I use the expression point_on_surface($geometry) to calculate the centre of gravity" but I don't think that 'point_on_surface' always return the center of gravity of a polygon (if you really need it use centroid)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

###### Area calculation

To get the upper, and lower areas using an expression, you can do something such as this.

I have chosen to have a string output in a single field. However, it could be a list, or a map, or the expression can be broken down to calculate the values separately in different fields.

```sql
-- centroid of the polygon
with_variable('c', centroid($geometry),
    -- make a line across the geometry at the centroid
    with_variable('c_l',
        make_line(
            make_point(x_min(@geometry), y(@c)),
            make_point(x_max(@geometry), y(@c))
        ),

        -- create a bounding box of the upper part of the polygon and intersect it with the polygon
        with_variable('upper',      
            intersection(       
                make_rectangle_3points(
                    start_point(@c_l),
                    end_point(@c_l),
                    make_point(x_max(@geometry), y_max(@geometry))
                ),              
                @geometry           
            ),

            -- create a bounding box of the lower part of the polygon and intersect it with the polygon
            with_variable('lower',
                intersection(
                    make_rectangle_3points(
                        start_point(@c_l),
                        end_point(@c_l),
                        make_point(x_max(@geometry), y_min(@geometry))
                    ),
                    @geometry
                ),

                -- concatenate areas in a string separated by a comma
                area(@upper) || ',' || area(@lower)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

###### Labels

For visualisation I created an expression that converts the output string above into an array and indexed each element as needed:

[image]

Label value expression

```sql
-- convert string to array of float values
with_variable('arr', array_foreach(string_to_array( "area_split" ), eval(@element)),

    -- index the array to get the upper and lower areas
    'total area: ' || to_int(area(@geometry)) || '\n' || 
    '------------' || '\n' ||
    'upper area: ' || to_int(@arr[0]) || '\n' || 
    'upper %: '    || round((@arr[0] / area(@geometry) * 100), 1) || '\n' || 
    '------------' || '\n' ||
    'lower area: ' || to_int(@arr[1]) || '\n' || 
    'lower %: '    || round(@arr[1] / area(@geometry) * 100, 1) || '\n'
)
```

###### Lines

To visualise the lines, I intersected the line generated through the centroid with the polygon geometry. This clips them to the original geometry, rather than leaving overhangs.

This expression was used on a *Geometry Generator* symbol layer

```sql
with_variable('c', centroid($geometry),
    intersection(
        make_line(
            make_point(x_min(@geometry), y(@c)),
            make_point(x_max(@geometry), y(@c))
        ),
        @geometry
    )
)
```

Comment: Solution implemented and working.
It is not clear to me the explanation to obtain the lines.
Could you share the expression that intersected the line generated through the centroid with the polygon geometry?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this in a few steps using a few processing tools:

1. Add an `area` field to your input polygon layer, you can do this by using Field Calculator and simply entering the expression `$area` (units will depend on your projection):

[image]

2. Use `Geometry by expression` and enter the following expression, setting the `Output geometry type` to `Line`:

   make_line(
   make_point(
   x_min($geometry),
   y(centroid($geometry))
   ),
   make_point(
   x_max($geometry),
   y(centroid($geometry))
   )
   )
3. Use the tool `Split with lines`, setting the `Input Layer` to your polygon layer and the `Split Layer` to the resultant `Modified Geometry` output from step 2.
4. Add a new area column (same as step 1) to add an area for each individual split polygon.
5. Divide this new area by the original area field to get the percent:

[image]